# ssrs : box sneaking to the left side of the footer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm creating a footer on my report, with 3 boxes. One on the left side, the second one in the middle and the last one on the right side.

The left box and right box are appearing on each page,  respectively with the timestamp info for the left box and for the number of pages for the right box.

Middle box is appearing , at the last page of the report only.

I've put the following line for my middle box

```
iif(Globals!PageNumber = Globals!TotalPages, False, True)
```

The script says the middle box will only appear at the last page of the report

Last page is fine. Three boxes, standing side by side.

Issue lies from the first page to the penultimate page.

As the middle box does not appear until the last page, the right box is shifting to the left side , taking over the place where the middle box should be.

I tried to fix this issue, by putting all the boxes in a rectangle. Alas no good news

I set the option `Keep Together = True` but I don't think it will help. I keep looking for a solution.

Any insights you may have , are more than welcome

Cheers

**Update** :

This is my last page

[image]

My second page to my penultimate page look like this

[image]

I want the third box to be on the extreme right side , like on my last page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, then the middle textbox has the following two properties set:

```
Visibility (hidden):    =IIF(Globals!PageNumber = Globals!TotalPages, False, True)
```

The value is : `"13779..."` or some expression evaluating to this.

Try changing these properties to the following:

```
Visibility(hidden): False
```

Then

```
Value: =IIF(Globals!PageNumber <> Globals!TotalPages, Nothing, "13779...")
```

This way you are not hiding the textbox itself, **just the text that it displays**.  Doing so should cause the textbox to align the same horizontally on all pages.

Comment: Hi @wesley-marshall, your answer is unclear ... Can you please reformulate , especially the last part `try setting the visibility to always show the box, then change the value of the textbox to display nothing except on the last page`. Can you reformat your answer, please? Your help will have a real impact on my work ... Thanks for your understanding

Comment: Thanks for the help. It took me some time to understand your answer but I got it, finally! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For the rightmost box make the right align the text.

Either by clicking on the menubar

[image]

OR

Change the textbox property `TextAlign` to `Right`

[image]

Another method will be to write an expression in `Left padding` for the rightmost text box.

Something Like

```
=iif(Globals!PageNumber = Globals!TotalPages, '2pt', '220pt')
```

Comment: Hi @anup-agrawal, can it be that simple...? Checking

Comment: Hi @AndyK Added another way to solve the same issue.

Comment: @AndyK Also you can try middle box and right box overlap each other and make middle box left align and right box right align.

Comment: @anu-agrawal Both solutions are not doing the trick, alas. Please find a graphical update of my issue

Comment: Did you try the other solution of aligning the textboxes on top of each other?

Comment: what do you mean by aligning the textboxes on top of each other?

Comment: Make your right box start from the same location as your middle box and the end location of your right box will be the end of the report. Now right align the text.

Comment: Also the indent expression make it something like 200pt. `=iif(Globals!PageNumber = Globals!TotalPages, '2pt', '220pt')`

Comment: Thanks for the help!